# Read consistency LOCAL_QUORUM implication in cassandra

Tags: cassandra

Thanks for your answer Nikita. Also, one more clarification. Assume I use LOCAL_QUORUM for read consistency in my multi-DC cluster with three DCs - DC1, DC2, DC3 with three nodes in each DC with replication factor of 3. During read, let us assume request first lands on a node in DC1. This node has failed and hence second node in DC1 is contacted and so on and assume all nodes in the DC1 have failed. Then will the cluster connect to either DC2 or DC3 to satisfy the LOCAL_QUORUM, i.e., look for acknowledgement from two consistent reads from either one of the DCs (either DC2 or DC3). I am not expecting one read from DC2 and another from DC3. What I mean to ask is if the cluster falls back on DC2 after all DC1 nodes fail, will it start evaluating the LOCAL_QUORUM factor within the perspective of DC2 and if yes, then will the cluster call it is a successful read?

Comment: is this supposed to be a comment to an earlier answer?

Comment: Where is the original Question? -1

Answer (score 0):

CQL query won't hit other data centers in case of LOCAL_QUORUM can't be succeed in local data center. However drivers implement such feature using DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy as you mentioned, but seems that it's [not recommended](https://medium.com/@foundev/cassandra-local-quorum-should-stay-local-c174d555cc57). Also [this article](https://medium.com/@foundev/cassandra-how-many-nodes-are-talked-to-with-quorum-also-should-i-use-it-98074e75d7d5) can be helpful for choosing of proper consistency level.